# Woocommerce checkout payment method hook

Tags: woocommerce

How to change the hook of the payment method in checkout page?

I found an actions that return order review form with payment method, but how to divide them? One action order review and one payment method

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' );
```

[image]

Comment: Great question, this was driving me nuts. I don't understand why WooCommerce would code it this complicated / inflexible

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two different actions are hooked into 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review'. Those are 'woocommerce_order_review' for order review and 'woocommerce_checkout_payment' for payment method.
This is defined in "*includes/wc-template-hooks.php*"

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );
```

Action hook 'woocommerce_order_review', calls template page "*checkout/review-order.php*".
Action hook 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', calls template page "*checkout/payment.php*"
Above two action/hook functions are defined in "*includes/wc-template-functions.php*"

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I call the two actions separately?

Comment: What exactly you want to do? If you can explain something more about what you want to achieve, may be based on that we can suggest further.

Comment: <div id="order-review">Here order review table</div>....<div id="checkout-payment">Here checkout payment</div>

Comment: You can copy the woocommerce template files (as mentioned in the response answer) into your theme. Location for those files should be "yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php" and "yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/payment.php". Then edit those files to add addition html markup.

Comment: I already tried it, this return error **Fatal error: Call to a member function get_title()**

Comment: If you are just adding additional html markup in the template files, it should not cause any error. Are you doing any thing else than just adding html?

Comment: Sorry, I copied `payment-method.php` instead `payment.php`. Now its working.

Comment: One more thing, how to dequeue `checkout payment` from `woocommerce_checkout_order_review`?

Comment: You call it as "unhook" in woocommerce terminology (just suggesting), and you can do that with "remove_action" hook. In this case you can add following line into your theme's function.php.
`remove_action('woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment');`

Comment: If your question is resolved, please mark the answer appropriately and close the question.

Comment: only `remove_action('woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment');` or `remove_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment');` does not remove the payment action from order review.

Comment: Sorry for that. Please try this. I have checked that this line worked.
`remove_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20);`

Comment: @zipkundan, thanks for your answer. How can we edit those files? Is it possible inside of the `wp-admin`, how?

Comment: @Sevi, How can we edit those files? Is it possible inside of the wp-admin, how?

Comment: @Igor Savinkin: which files you want to edit? Rather explain what you want to achieve. Some one can guide you based on that.

Comment: @zipkundan files: `woocommerce_checkout_payment`, `checkout/payment.php` . I suppose, this might help me to fix a bug; see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36356697/1230477)

Comment: I checked that thread. I don't think editing woocommerce files will help you. Most probably the issue seems to be with the plugin which is not updated for too long.

Comment: If anyways you want to edit those file, you will have to copy those template files into your theme directory. `your-theme/woocommerce/checkout/file-name.php`

Comment: @zipkundan **you're hero! Thanks a lot for this!**